# focus to input element on mobile when keyboard pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I want to scroll the page/form to focus when the user clicks on an input field, and the keyboard pops up, in order to show that input field in the current view.

I am trying these two solutions, but none of them works:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop += this.getBoundingClientRect().top - 10
});
```

and

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0,0);
});
```

how can I do it? why none of these is working?

Comment: Do any of your examples actually scroll but just to wrong location, or they don't scroll at all?

Answer (score 0):

.scrollTop() is a method and only accepts one value.

Your first example is wrong as you cannot use += to add to it. You would need to pass it a vertical value like .scrollTop(0).

Your second example is wrong as you are giving two values to it. I think your are getting confused with .scrollTo(0,0) instead of scrollTop().

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Example (not tested):

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(this.getBoundingClientRect().top - 10);
});
```

Comment: so what is a correct answer? could you suggest a fix?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.